# How to add custom subject/header to mail() only called from within a specific folder

Tags: php, linux, apache, email, .htaccess

I have a PHP script that is uploaded to a `/folder`

It has several pages where uses the mail() function of PHP.
I would like to alter the subject eg: [folder] when the mail() function is called from the script that resides in the /folder.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can find what folder the current script is in with `__DIR__` magic constant
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

If you use some standard library to send emails, your script might look similar to this.

```
$folder = end(explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, __DIR__));
// or dirname(__FILE__) instead of __DIR_ for PHP 5.2

$mail = new Mail();
$mail->addTo('email@example.com')
     ->subject('['.$folder.'] subject')
     ->send();
```

Comment: I said I am using the PHP mail() function, and I've several pages. I am looking to some global way, to set once, and to work for all files in the folder and subdirectory.

Comment: It does not really matter if you use mail() or other function to send emails. The core part is the `$folder` variable which determines the current path and extracts the last folder. You can then add the `$folder` variable directly into subject.

Comment: The problem is that I have to edit each file that sends the email. And I don't know all of them, and can be many. I need some other way doing this.

Comment: How do you know which file to call? At some point you must do an include I suppose. Couldn't you setup some global variable there?